# Why can't I return a Dataset from a function inside a VB.net class?

Tags: vb.net, function, class, dataset

I am using WinForms and trying to retrieve all the data from the database once on form Load so I won't have to go back and forth to the database a lot.

I created a class and wrote a function that returns a dataset but I'm not being able to refer to it from my forms.

This is the code:

```
Private Function FillKeywords() As DataSet
    Dim ds1 As DataSet : Dim cmd as SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Dbo.selectkeywords", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        ds1 = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds1, "Keywords")
        Return ds1
    Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
        WriteExToFile(ex.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteExToFile(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: your function should be "public" so that it can be accessed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess and say you will need to lose the `Private` keyword if you want your function to be accessible from another class or module.